# DNS requests blocked by iptables

Tags: iptables, router

I am currently setting up IP Tables for our network. We have the following networking situation:

We have 3 networks, the grey, green and red. The grey network has full internet access without restrictions, but no access to green or red. Green has access to grey and to the internet without restrictions, red has no internet access and access to green and grey.

Grey has the IP range 192.168.178.0/24 (on interface eth_grey)
Green has the IP range 192.168.50.0/24 (on interface eth_green)
Red has the IP range 192.168.40.0/24 (on interface eth_red)

I have set up the following rules in my rules.v4 (currently there is no ipv6, this will be configured later, ipv6 is set to an accept policy):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth_grey -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT


*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP

# Allow all loopback traffic and traffic from established connections.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic in the internal network
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.40.0/24 -d 192.168.40.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.50.0/24 -d 192.168.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.178.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Allow traffic from red to green
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.40.0/24 -d 192.168.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Allow traffic from green to grey
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.50.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Allow traffic from red to grey
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.40.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all traffic in the grey network
-A INPUT -i eth_grey -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Allo outgoing traffic from the sales network
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Forward traffic from eth_green to eth_grey
-A FORWARD -i eth_green -o eth_grey -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Accept ICMP and SSH.
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

The situation is now, that traffic from green to the internet is allows, e.g. I can ping `8.8.8.8`. What I cannot do is resolve DNS. On the router DNSmasq is installed. I even cant resolve DNS on the router directly when connected with SSH, but when I set the policy to accept and flush the rules I can resolve DNS, so I assume DNSMasq is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to carefully re-read the iptables documentation.

Please have a look at this diagram, visualizing the iptables chains: https://github.com/rda0/diagram/blob/master/iptables-chains-hooks.png

Almost all the rules you will want to have to setup what you describe have to be in the `FORWARD` chain. All packets that need to be routed (meaning: coming from one network range to another) pass through this chain.

The `INPUT` chain is for all packets targetet to the local system (the router) and the `OUTPUT` chain is for packets originating from the local system.

Your policies are all `DROP`. So you need to open some ports to allow DNS traffic.

For example, to allow DNS locally on the router when you test via ssh you need to open port `53` in the `OUTPUT` chain.

I don't understand which interface is connected to the internet. But to allow DNS from your networks, you have to open port `53` in the `FORWARD` chain, with a rule something like this:

```
-A FORWARD -i <local_if> -o <inet_if> --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Where `local_if` is one of your networks and `inet_if` is the interface connected to the internet.

I would also recommend to accept `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` traffic in both `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` chains.

Rules #3-5: traffic like this will never hit your router, because it does not need routing.